# Перенос скомпилированного модуля ядра на другую машину

Tags: linux, компиляция, kernel, модули

Чем больше читаю информации по модулям ядра, тем больше возникает вопросов. Могу ли я скомпилировать модуль ядра на одной машине и перенести этот скомпилированный модуль на другую. Ядро у этих машин как правило совпадает(максимум может отличаться на несколько версий, например 3.0.1 и 3.0.22), тип процессора одинаковый. Вроде есть VERMAGIC для определения совпадения версии, есть еще module versioning, которая cравнивает хеши символов модуля и ядра. Успешная загрузка модуля также зависит от конфига ядра и kernel.symversions. Например, драйвера для NVIDIA как-то тащатся через DKMS бинарными. Так могу ли я скомпилировать модуль на одной машине и просто скопировать его на остальные?

Comment: для компиляции модуля нужны исходники программы *linux* (хотя бы заголовочные файлы) ровно той же версии (и с тем же конфигом). ну и, естественно, «джентльменский набор» — компилятор, make, и т.д. // в случае dkms всё перечисленное (плюсь само dkms-овское «хозяйство») должно присутствовать на целевой машине — именно там происходит сборка модуля-«прокладки» между проприетарным блобом и программой *linux*.

Comment: А можно узнать: зачем именно переносить?

Comment: Если коротко, то в общем случае нет. Если хочется, то необходимы такие же заголовочные файлы, как на целевой машине, и набор компиляторов, способный сгенерировать код под целевую архитектуру.

Comment: @donRumata, есть несколько почти одинаковых машин, на которых тестируется один и тот же модуль. не хочется ждать когда скомпилируется на каждой машине. Вот и было желание компилировать на одной машине и сбрасывать на остальные

Comment: @0andriy, да я про это в курсе. допустим есть две машины с одинаковым ядром и типом процессора. я скачиваю header-ы на одной машине, компилирую модуль и переношу его на другую машину. Будет ли корректно работать модуль?

Comment: Да абсолютно не важно, какое ядро установлено и работает на машине, где вы собираетесь компилировать модуль. Важно, чтобы на ней присутствовали необходимые для сборки модуля для целевой системы!

Answer (score 1):

Любой модуль ядра обращается к функциям, входящим в состав самого ядра. Для того, что бы выполнить команду вызова функции, подгружаемый модуль должен знать **адрес** точки входа в эту функцию. Т.е. модуль должен быть правильно слинкован с **конкретным** вариантом ядра.

Очевидно, что адреса точек входа в функции ядра могут меняться не только от версии к версии, но даже при изменении конфигурационного файла генерации ядра.

Именно поэтому, при сборке загружаемого модуля ядра всегда проверяется наличие объектных файлов ядра, из которых и выбираются адреса точек входа в функции ядра.

Comment: Последний абзац не соответствует действительности.

Comment: @0andriy Т.е. Вы утверждаете, что можно слинковать модуль, не имея объектного кода ядра? Откуда же тогда берётся таблица перекрёстных ссылок?

Comment: Я надеюсь, что Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini, и Greg Kroah-Hartman, написавшие библию разработчиков драйверов. "Драйверы Устройств Linux (3-я редакция) являются для Вас авторитетом?

Вот, что они пишут на странице 14 главы 2:

"Независимо от происхождения ядра, сборка модулей для 2.6.x требует, чтобы вы имели сконфигурированное и собранное дерево ядра на своей системе. Это требование является изменением относительно предыдущей версии ядра, когда текущего набора заголовочных файлов было достаточно."

Comment: @Sergey, в LDD3 ошибка. неточность или устаревшая информация... я несколько раз на это натыкался уже... на самом деле достаточно «сконфигурированного» дерева хедеров, куда входят сами хедеры, корневой Makefile, `.config`, а также один файл оставшийся от сборки — `Module.symvers`. В нём собственно и находится список всех экспортируемых символов ядра с их адресами. Собственно это содержимое любого пакета `linux-headers` в пакетных дистрибутивах, которого *достаточно* для сборки модулей. Всё дерево сборки или исходников таскать за собой не нужно.

Comment: @Sergey, возможно, описанное относилось к некоторым из версий 2.6.x программы *linux*, пока это явное неудобство не устранили («когда текущего набора заголовочных файлов было достаточно») практика — критерий истины. вот [список содержимого](http://paste.debian.net/1052585/) каталогов `/lib/modules/*` для сборки модулей (у меня на работе). никаких существующих модулей, как видно, нет, но модули в этих chroot-ах [отлично компилируются](http://repo.drweb.com/drweb/linux/11.1/x86_64/drweb-spider-kmod-11.1.0-1811011309linux.x86_64.rpm). и зоопарк версий *linux*, как видно, достаточно разнообразный.

Comment: *If you still do not have a kernel tree handy, or have not yet configured and built that kernel, now is the time to go do it. You cannot build loadable modules for a 2.6 kernel without this tree on your filesystem. It is also helpful (though not required) to be actually running the kernel that you are building for.* Найдите десять отличий. А откуда вы взяли процитированное вами, оставим на вашей совести.

Comment: @0andriy - Обращаю Ваше внимание на то, что Вы сами(!) написали: *один файл оставшийся от сборки — Module.symvers.* Повторяю: **оставшийся от сборки**. Значит - сборку всё-таки **нужно** делать ? А То, что эту сборку сделал кто-то за Вас, сути не меняет. Я, к примеру, делал драйверы для ARM и PowerPC, самостоятельно собирая ядра, конкретно под нашу железяку.

Comment: @Sergey, 1. да исправьте ж вы в конце концов третий абзац: в текущем ввиде он вводит в заблуждение, о чём вам три человека написали. 2. вам писали три человека, а не один, обращайте, пожалуйста, чуть больше внимания на авторство (это я по поводу предыдущего комментария «Вы сами(!) написали»).

Comment: @alexander_barakin *да исправьте ж вы в конце концов третий абзац* - и написать что? Что объектники НЕ нужны для сборки модуля? Весь мой почти 10-летний опыт написания драйверов говорит об обратном. Если я внёс хотя бы малейшее изменение в конфиг генерации ядра, то НЕОБХОДИМО сначала пересобрать ядро, а затем уже - собирать драйвер. Даже одна и та же версия/релиз ядра будут иметь разную таблицу перекрёстных ссылок, при разных конфигурациях.

Та что свой ответ я изменять не буду. Если он Вам не нравится - напишите свой. В чём проблема?

Comment: ***Если** я внёс хотя бы малейшее **изменение** в конфиг генерации ядра, то **НЕОБХОДИМО** сначала **пересобрать** ядро, а затем уже - собирать драйвер* — так вы напишите **об этом**, а не про какую-то там «проверку наличия».